# R, summary on regsubsets: how skip force.in in printing

Tags: r

I have a data set cigs on which I call 
`q=regsubsets(Sales~Age+HS+Income+Black+Female+Price, data=cigs, method="exhaustive")`

I would like to skip in the summary(q) the below part:

`Subset selection object
Call: regsubsets.formula(Sales ~ Age + HS + Income + Black + Female + 
    Price, data = cigs, method = "exhaustive")
6 Variables  (and intercept)
       Forced in Forced out
Age        FALSE      FALSE
HS         FALSE      FALSE
Income     FALSE      FALSE
Black      FALSE      FALSE
Female     FALSE      FALSE
Price      FALSE      FALSE
1 subsets of each size up to 6`

and keep in only his part:

`Selection Algorithm: exhaustive
         Age HS  Income Black Female Price
1  ( 1 ) " " " " "*"    " "   " "    " "
2  ( 1 ) " " " " "*"    " "   " "    "*"
3  ( 1 ) "*" " " "*"    " "   " "    "*"
4  ( 1 ) "*" " " "*"    "*"   " "    "*"
5  ( 1 ) "*" " " "*"    "*"   "*"    "*"
6  ( 1 ) "*" "*" "*"    "*"   "*"    "*"`

Do you know if I can do that? I tried `capture.output` but it transforms `"` into `\"` and I cannot really transform it back...

Comment: Does `capture.output` only add the backslash? Because that can be taken out.

Comment: Using the capture.output I get something like this `"1  ( 1 )  \" \"  \" \"  \"* \"  \" \" \" \"  \" \" "`. I 've been trying `gsub("([\\])","", str)` but I keep getting the same...

Comment: compare `print(str)` and `cat(str)`

Comment: It looks like R added backslashes, but that is just a printing method.

Comment: It is, but I'd like to show the result in a pdf using knitr and those extra backslashes make it hard to read :-( .

Comment: use `cat` or `writeLines` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, this will give you the output:

```
summary(q)$outmat
```

`outmat` on the `summary` of the model returns you only the matrix.